# What's the difference between?

Tags: python, string, eval

```
string1 = "15 > 4 "
string2 = "'15' > '4'"
print(eval(string1))
print(eval(string2))
```

```
True
False
```

Just like the title says. Why do you have different values for the same string?

Comment: because `'1' < '4'`

Comment: and `'1111111111111' > '2'` is `False` - its called lexicographical comparison - in constrast to comparing numerical.

Comment: Why do you think they are the same string? Does `"15 > 4"` have `'` symbols in it? Does `"'15' > '4'"` have `'` symbols in it? Isn't that different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No these are different, because the first one compares two integers, but the second one compares to strings.

Python string comparison is performed using the characters in both strings. The characters in both strings are compared one by one. When different characters are found then their Unicode value is compared. The character with lower Unicode value is considered to be smaller.

and here `ord('1')` is 49 and `ord('4')` is 52, so `49 < 52` I mean `'1' < '4'` so it is `False`.

Comment: Thanks for including the Unicode aspect.  Strong answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the string 1, eval() will treat the comparisaon like comparing two ints, whereas with the string 2, it will treat it as if it's comparing two strings.

15 > 4 (ints) = True

'15' > '4' (strings) = False

While comparing the "15" string with the "4" string, it will compare the strings character by character, and therefore 15 is considered smaller because the string starts with a "1", which is smaller than "4" when converted to their Unicode values.

If you were to do something like this :

```py
string1 = "55 > 4 "
string2 = "'55' > '4'"
print(eval(string1))
print(eval(string2))
```

The output would be :

```py
True
True
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are comparing integers.
In the second case you are comparing strings.

Since strings are compared character by character and 4 is greater than 1, the statement `'15' > '4'` evaluates to `False`.